# Unset all defined variables from the current function

Tags: php, function, variables, unset

For example, I have this function:

```
function foo($whaaaat){

  $var1 = 'a';  
  $a = 1;
  $b = 2;

  ...


  // here unset all variables defined above (including arguments) 
  require 'somefile.php';
}
```

So, can I unset all those variables before the require point?

Obviously without calling unset manually on each variable, because that I figured out myself :)

Is there some function that does this?

Comment: Why are you needing to unset them?

Comment: @jprofitt: Kind of an irrelevant question don't you think?

Comment: True, but curiosity prevails. Re-reading my comment, I wasn't really meaning to sound like I was judging the question or asker...honest!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming none of those in-function variables are declared global, you could try something like

```
array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $GLOBALS)
```

to get a list of the local variables, then loop over the results to unset them.

Comment: `var_dump(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $GLOBALS));` appears to be missing locally created arrays...

Comment: Great point however it's true that is missing locally created arrays!

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap the `require` in an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
function foo($a){
  $b = 2;

  call_user_func(function() {
   require 'somefile.php';
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like so:

```
function require_noscope($filename)
{
    // Required file cannot see variables from other function
    require $filename;
}

function foo($whaaaat){

  $var1 = 'a';  
  $a = 1;
  $b = 2;
  require_noscope('somefile.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work (untested):

```
$allVars = get_defined_vars(); // Returns array of all defined variables
foreach ($allVars as $allVars) { unset($allVars); }
```

Edit: As I said, never tested nor ever used this, but it could lead Alex in the right direction.

Comment: That includes $GLOBALS as of PHP 5.0, however, so you'd be unsetting everything in the parent scope, including the SUPERGLOBALS - very bad.

Comment: This doesn't work, as unset($allVars) is "unsetting" the value of the variable, not the name of it, or the variable itself, as it needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
echo('Before: ' . $test1 . '<br>');

$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
foreach($vars as $var) {
    if($var == 'GLOBALS' || $var == '_POST' || $var == '_GET' || $var == '_COOKIE' || $var == '_FILES' || $var == '_REQUEST' || $var == '_SERVER' || $var == '_ENV')
        continue;
    unset($$var);
}
echo('After: ' . $test1 . '<br>');
```

My test outputs this:

> Before: here?
>
> After:

Comment: You forgot the REQUEST, SERVER, and ENV superglobals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but looking at that `if` statement now, there's bound to be a better way...

Comment: The array_diff() version in a couple answers here is probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in, but you can use the [get_defined_vars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) function to get an array of all defined variables, then use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to unset them.  You'll get it all done in 4 lines that way, and it's flexible.

```
$list_of_vars =  array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $GLOBALS); // Was just get_defined_vars() before Marc B corrected me in his post.
foreach($list_of_vars as $var){
    unset($var);
}
```

Edit: As Marc B pointed out, this will unset your $GLOBAL variables too.  I've edited my example to show how to properly get the list of variables.

Comment: That includes $GLOBALS as of PHP 5.0, however, so you'd be unsetting everything in the parent scope, including the SUPERGLOBALS - very bad.

Comment: Very true, good catch.  I've given yours the up and made note in mine.

Comment: This doesn't work, as unset($var) is "unsetting" the value of the variable, not the name of it, or the variable itself, as it needs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Whetstone. `get_defined_vars()` is just perfect for "multi-unset" tricks.
This method below, unsets ALL variables. **All except those found within nameless array** inside foreach loop.

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $k=>$y){ 
 if( !in_array( $k, 
 array(
  'myRequredVariableName1',
  'myRequredVariableName2',
  '_ENV',
  '_SESSION',
   '_COOKIE',
  'HTTP_SESSION_VARS',
  'HTTP_COOKIE_VARS'
  )))
  { $$k=null; unset($$k);} 
    unset($y, $k);
} 

// Check for leftovers
header('Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
var_export(get_defined_vars()); 
exit;
```

The values are actually variable names without '$', where variable variable `unset($$k);` matches the REAL and defined one, and destroys it, if it is present. So, on this way, You can have complete control over what is left for system.

***Note*** that some shared hosting setups are relying only on _SERVER superglobals, therefore _ENV, HTTP_SESSION_VARS, HTTP_COOKIE_VARS are not required at all. Most probably You'll always want to keep _COOKIE and _SESSION but not _GET and _POST as well or _FILES. The decision varies. Test and see for Your self what should stand within array before putting this trick on Your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Needed this, and the existing answers here weren't really helpful. The following is short, to the point, and works:

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $k => $v)
    unset($$k);
unset($k, $v);
```

If calling `var_dump(get_defined_vars())` after this, you will get an empty array.

---

***Note:*** Unless in global scope (which the question is not, it's in a function), the `get_defined_vars` won't return any globals, so no need to filter or check anything, just unset it all.